npm dependencies from private repository
I'm trying to use a package I've created in my vue3 application; the package is hosted in a private repository;
in particular the package uses json-editor-vue 0.15.1 that depends on vanilla-jsoneditor 0.23.2 that depends on json-source-map 0.6.1 which is causing the issue;
basically if I install the package from a local directory with npm link (so first running npm install in the package's directory) everything works fine.
if I try to install it from my repository (using git+https://repositoryUrl) then nothing works;
in the package I have "json-editor-vue": "^0.15.1" in dependencies section of its package.json;
launching the app now results in having this error:
The requested module '/node_modules/json-source-map/index.js?v=a9c71748' does not provide an export named 'default' that is coming from `node_modules/vanilla-jsoneditor/index.js
I can't really understand why, since the dependencies looks installed correctly:
in the package local folder, after doing npm install I have node_modules/json-source-map folder that contains version 0.6.1 as expected (and using my package from local folder works as I wrote above).
when installing the package from remote repository then in my vue3 app I have node_modules/my-package and node_modules/json-source-map that so has been moved to a top level dependency, I guess because it's a common dependency with some other package; so everything is there but running the app leads to the error I wrote above...
also trying to manually copy the json-source-map folder into node_modules/my-package/node_modules has no effect
